# Angular ui-router: is there a way to extend an existing state in another module's config block?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm working on an extremely modular application, some 3rd party modules must be abble to be plugged or removed from the core without breaking the main functionalities. And in my case I would need a 'plugin' module to be abble to register a view in a state already defined by the core module. Something like this:

```
angular
    .module('myApp', [])
    .config(function($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state('myState', {
            views: {
                mainView: { templateUrl: 'mainTpl.html' }
            }
        });
    })
;

angular
    .module('myPlugin', [])
    .config(function($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider.extendState('myState', {
            views: {
                otherView: { templateUrl: 'otherTpl.html' }
            }
        });
    })
;
```

I've tried to achieve this by extending the given state in the run block, but as the state is already registered, it has no effect.

```
angular
    .module('myPlugin', [])
    .run(function($state) {
        // this does not work...
        angular.merge($state.get('myState'), {
            views: {
                otherView: { templateUrl: 'otherTpl.html' }
            }
        });
    })
;
```

Thx

Comment: Hope some angular ninja have a solution for this. Having the same issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you need, but you can nest states like this:

```
$stateProvider.extendState('myState.childState' , {
```

This way you can inherit properties defined in the parent state, e.g. `params`.

See [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views).